# Swift Problems - NSUserDefault and Settings Bundle not responding

Tags: ios, if-statement, boolean, swift, nsuserdefaults

So I had set up a settings bundle to just do one thing. Allow the Users to choose between the The TouchUI and GestureUI in my app and for some odd reason, I am unable to get the Settings Bundle to control it. It stays with one and doesn't switch even when I have the If else Statement. originally I had `var touchCheck = userDefaults.boolForKey("myGestureEnabledDisabled")` but it didn't change boolean at all when i keep  closing app(Multitask > SwipeUp app) and re running the app via springboard. The Settings App could have the bundle at `NO` but log says gestures are on. After watching a Tutorial, i changed `boolForKey` to `valueForKey` which causes the build to fail and there is no error in the code the way i have it below.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.synchronize()
    var touchCheck = Bool(userDefaults.valueForKey("myGestureEnabledDisabled"))

    if touchCheck {

        whenGuestureIsEnabled()

    } else {

        whenGestureIsDisabled()
        self.navBar.hidden = false

    }
}

func whenGuestureIsEnabled() {

    NSLog("Gesture is suppose to be on")
}

func whenGestureIsDisabled() {

    NSLog("Gesture is OFF")

}
```

Maybe from what I was thinking, I shouldn't do this in UIViewController but I had seen this in action in a youtube tutorial and it was in OBJ-C.

Comment: Finally was this problem fixed? I'm searching the whole internet for an answer and still can't get the settings bundle to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast to bool, not to create a new one:

```
//notice (Bool) cast in the beginning 
var touchCheck = (Bool)userDefaults.valueForKey("myGestureEnabledDisabled")
```

Comment: I had this at one point but wasn't able to get Settings Bundle to change the bool value and cause the touchUI to enable. it would keep the `navBar` hidden.